# How to change the anchoring type in algolia query

Tags: php, wordpress, algolia

I am looking for a way to customize the plugin in order to generate search results that starts with the query string. Like if I have a list of countries and regions of Asia in Algolia and query string is ‘In’ then the search should only fetch countries that starts with ‘In’ only like India, Indonesia and so on. It should not fetch those countries which contains ‘In’ in their names like Singapore, British Indian Ocean Territory.